# Determine what user account iTextSharp runs as

Tags: c#, itext

I have a website where users can upload PDF files and I then parse them using iTextSharp.

The uploaded files are saved to a network share without a problem. I then pass the file path of the newly saved file to iTextSharp:

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
```

But I get:

```
Error: \\networkshare\savedPDF.pdf not found as file or resource. File: \\networkshare\savedPDF.pdf
```

Looking at the [source code](http://www.java2v.com/Open-Source/CSharp/PDF/iTextSharp/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfFileSpecification.cs.htm) I see that it was not able to get the file stream:

```
inp = BaseFont.GetResourceStream(filePath);
if (inp == null)
    throw new IOException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("1.not.found.as.file.or.resource", filePath));
```

Since this code works fine on my machine and the file does exist, I can only assume that it is a permissions issue. This issue is only present in production.

**How can I determine/set the user that the component runs as?**

Comment: In IIS configuration for the application.

Comment: Does this mean that the account that is used to write the uploaded file is the same account used by iTextSharp or can they be different?

Comment: iTextSharp is regular code running in your process.  It uses the same credentials.

Comment: The user should be the same if the iTextSharp DLL is being used as part of the .NET solution. There could be separate users if the iTextSharp functionality is being invoked via a standalone web service or something.

Comment: @criticalfix I think that's it! The file is saved by the controller, but the PDF is parsed on a different services box.